# PHP Symfony Convert Propel Choice to String

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

I am using a propel form to allow a user to create an account, the form has two parts; the entering and then the preview.

On my preview page I declare the values of the form as usual and these are provided by the previous form

```
public function configure() {
    //Preview page no fields are displayed anyway xD
    $this->useFields(array('email', 'user_gender_id', 'search_gender_id', 'content', 'age', 'location'));
```

But instead of outputting the fields I am trying to render the values on the page:

```
<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(); ?>

    <?php foreach($form as $field): ?>

        <?php if(!$field->isHidden()): ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $field->renderLabel() ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $field->getValue(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php echo $form; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Unfortunately for my sfWidgetFormPropelChoice / sfWidgetFormChoice fields it just outputs the chosen ID rather than a string representation of it.

Is there a proper way in Symfony to output the text representation of a widget's value? Or do I have to hack something together? (any ideas?)

Many thanks,

Pez,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by doing the following:

```
<td><?php if(method_exists($field->getWidget(), "getChoices")) {
    $choices = $field->getWidget()->getChoices();
     echo $choices[$field->getValue()];
} else
     echo $field->getValue();
?></td>
```

I hope this is of use to someone as it has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$obj = $form->getObject();
```

to have the values of your object. Then:

```
echo $obj[$field->getName()];
```

this can work in most cases. But, if it won't, you'll have to write all the preview fields by hand and display them using the `$obj` above.